# PHP update order by date added not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

```
function post_data($update_data){
    $session_user_id = $_SESSION ['user_id'];

    $user_data = user_data($session_user_id,  'username', 'email');
    $email= $user_data['email'];

    $update= array();

    array_walk($update_data, 'array_sanitize');

    foreach ($update_data as $field => $data) {
        $update[] = '`'. $field . '` =\''.$data .'\'';
    }

    mysql_query("UPDATE `user_post` SET " . implode(', ', $update) . " WHERE `email` = '$email' ORDER BY date_added DESC  ");

}
```

Hi, the function above update a mysql table, please how do i make sure that when the code is executed, it is displayed in the order of last inserted.

This is the code that fetch the values from the table;

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  user_post WHERE `username` = '$get_user' ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 3 ");
$newsCount = @mysql_num_rows($query); // count the output amount

if ($newsCount > 0) {

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $id = $row["id"];
        $username = $row["username"];
        $body =     $row["body"];
        $profile_pix = $row["profile_pix"];
        $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: mind changing the caps to lowercase/camel case? it's considered as shouting

Comment: for what i know an order by in an update  is non sense ..the update happen without any order ..and should produce an error

Comment: seeing that pending edit http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15640993 - that's "your" job, not others'.

Comment: Describing the observed behavior as "not working" is abysmally inadequate. If the SELECT statement is returning rows in an unexpected order, then likely the ORDER BY clause is using an expression which doesn't sort in the "order" you expect. The most likely explanation for this is that the `date_added` column is not a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP, and values stored in the column are not canonical... for example, storing strings in the form "March 23, 2017 12:41". Is there a *reason* we are using the deprecated mysql interface and not mysqli or PDO?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could add a 'created_at' column in your table, and then order your query by 'created_at'.

Comment: I'v something similar 'date_added'

Comment: My guess (just a guess) is that the *datatype* of `date_added` is not DATE or DATETIME, probably VARCHAR, and the values stored in the column are not canonical (an ORDER BY doesn't return the values in a "date time" sequence.  for example storing "March 25, 2017",  or '3/27/17'. I think this answer is suggesting that the column `created_at` be declared as DATETIME or TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Spencer may be right. The data type could be the problem. Maybe you are using DATE. Instead le DATETIME. If that the case, It won't order dates Who were created the same day, beacause they will be the same.